# invalid token in class declaration?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have this code taken from Fo Dicom open source library , the code not compiling because the compiler complain that there are invalid tokens .

```
        /// <inheritdoc />
        public bool IsEOF => _stream.Position >= _stream.Length;
```

the error in this piece of code :

> Error 101 Invalid token '>=' in class, struct, or interface member declaration    c:\Users\user\Desktop\New folder\fo-dicom-development\DICOM\IO\FileByteSource.cs    93  47  DICOM.Desktop

why this happening ?

Comment: you're not showing the code causing the error.

Comment: sorry I edited it with another error

Comment: end the statement with a `;` and ensure your code is contained inside a class.

Comment: Are you compiling under C# 6 or later?

Comment: Alternatively, tell us which version of Visual Studio you're using.

Comment: @Aominè simicolon was in the original code but i removed it by accident when pasting code here

Comment: @BenCottrell   I'm using .NET 4.7.1 and i guess the compiler version is 7

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm using visual studio 2013

Comment: Well that's the problem then. Visual Studio 2013 uses the C# 5 compiler, and you're trying to use a C# 6 feature. (I doubt that you're actually using .NET 4.7.1 either. You may have that installed, but that doesn't mean you're targeting that in your project. It's *possible* that a VS2013 update makes that work, but it doesn't change which compiler version you're using.)

Comment: I'm surprised the compiler is OK with `=>` but not OK with `>=` in this example.

Comment: @serpent5 I highly suspect that it's not OK with =>, and that >= is a red herring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need c# 7 compiler to compile that type of member declaration.

Since you are using VS 2013 you get older version of c# compiler that does not know about this syntax and will fail to compile somewhere *near* the `=>` as compiler always tries to male sense of as much code as possible. If you really interested why error reported on next operation grab the specification for c# version you actually end up using and figure out how it interprets `public bool a => b ...`.